# How can you authenticate requests made to a Discord interactions webhook in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, discord

According to the [Discord documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#receiving-an-interaction), webhooks must validate the headers on every request in order to be accepted. The documentation provides the following code sample:

```
const nacl = require('tweetnacl');

// Your public key can be found on your application in the Developer Portal
const PUBLIC_KEY = 'APPLICATION_PUBLIC_KEY';

const signature = req.get('X-Signature-Ed25519');
const timestamp = req.get('X-Signature-Timestamp');
const body = req.rawBody; // rawBody is expected to be a string, not raw bytes

const isVerified = nacl.sign.detached.verify(
  Buffer.from(timestamp + body),
  Buffer.from(signature, 'hex'),
  Buffer.from(PUBLIC_KEY, 'hex')
);

if (!isVerified) {
  return res.status(401).end('invalid request signature');
}
```

How do you do this in .NET 5.0? I haven't been able to find any examples of Ed25519 validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation requires the [NSec.Cryptography NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSec.Cryptography/20.11.0-preview1).

First, you must create an ActionFilter to place on your WebAPI controller or endpoints. The simplest way to do this is by extending ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class DiscordAuthorizationActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // This is needed to move the request stream to the beginning as it has already been evaluated for model binding
        context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var signature = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Signature-Ed25519"].FirstOrDefault();
        var timestamp = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Signature-Timestamp"].FirstOrDefault();
        var body = await new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var key = "{YOUR API KEY HERE}";
        var algorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.Ed25519;
        var publicKey = PublicKey.Import(algorithm, GetBytesFromHexString(key), KeyBlobFormat.RawPublicKey);
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timestamp + body);
        var verified = algorithm.Verify(publicKey, data, GetBytesFromHexString(signature));

        if (!verified)
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult("Invalid request");
        else
            await next();
    }

    private byte[] GetBytesFromHexString(string hex)
    {
        var length = hex.Length;
        var bytes = new byte[length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Note this comment:

```
// This is needed to move the request stream to the beginning as it has already been evaluated for model binding
context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

To allow the request body stream to be reused, you must explicitly enable this in the request pipeline prior to the first time it is accessed, likely during model binding. To do this, you can add a simple step in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    // This is needed to retrieve request body as JSON string in ActionFilter
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var controller = context.Request.RouteValues["controller"] as string;

        if (controller == "Discord")
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();

        await next();
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
}
```

Notice the check for the controller name; since I placed the attribute on DiscordController, the controller value stored in the RouteValues collection is "Discord".

Finally, simply add the attribute to an endpoint that accepts POST requests:

```
public class DiscordController : ControllerBase
{
    [DiscordAuthorizationActionFilter]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(DiscordInteraction interaction)
    {
        if (interaction == null)
            return BadRequest();

        if (interaction.Type == DiscordInteractionType.Ping)
            return Ok(new { Type = 1 });

        // Request processing here

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Note that the DiscordInteraction model is custom code not available in any libraries that I'm aware of. It is simple to create this by following the documentation. To test this, I found it helpful to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to route requests from Discord to my development environment.